# TimeSpan.ParseExact with ms

Tags: c#, timespan

Trying to parse the following time

```
string time = "12:25:1197";
TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.ParseExact(time, "HH.mm.ssff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Shouldn't be 12:25:11.97 instead?

Comment: no, the sting is exactly the same (no . for ms)

Comment: Then the string does not match the specified format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you are using `.` as a separator, but your string uses `:`.

Second, that is a quite weird representation of seconds (which is a 60 based number) and milliseconds (which is a 100-based one), so you more likely have:

```
string time = "12:25:11.97" // remember the quotes
```

Which should be parsed with:

```
TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.ParseExact(time, "hh':'mm':'ss.ff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If you indeed have `12:25:1197` then you can use `hh':'mm':'ssff`, but that's indeed weird

Btw, if that's two digits for what you call `ms`, then that's `hundreths of seconds`, not `milliseconds` (which woulf be three digits)

Comment: no, the sting is exactly the same string format (no '.' between sec and ms)

Comment: ok, then, `HH':'mm':'ssff` should work as i put on the last paragraph

Comment: HH':'mm':'ssff gives me exception

Comment: Sorry, that should be lowercase `hh`

Comment: @user829174 because `hh` expects single digit hours to have a leading zero (that is: `09`). Change to single `h` if they don't have it

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
TimeSpan t = TimeSpan.ParseExact(time, "hh\\:mm\\:ssff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Based on: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287.aspx#Other